# can i have an ordered dictionary by date

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

i have a dictionary where the key is a date and the value is an object.  is there anyway i can ensure that when i loop through this collection its in chronological order always even after adding and deleting items.

Comment: Presumably your not adding whilst you loop round?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ:

```
foreach(var kvp in dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)) {
    //Use kvp.Key and kvp.Value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SortedList:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx
or SortedDictionary: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx